# Double Colon "::" operator in C/assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

First off, no, I'm not talking about the C++ scope resolution operator.

I have the following syntax:

```
asm(
"mov R0,%0\n"
"mov R1,%1\n"
"mov R3,%2\n"
"mov R4,%3\n"
"mov R5,%4\n"
::"r"(<A_VALUE>),
"r"(<A_VALUE>),
"r"(<A_VALUE>),
"r"(<A_VALUE>),
"r"(<A_VALUE>),
:"r0","r1","r2"
)
```

What does colon and the double colon mean?
I do remember something having to do with string concatenation when dynamically creating variable names.

Million thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The `::` isn't an operator, it's two `:` separators. See [GCC Manual - Extended ASM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) for more details.

```
asm asm-qualifiers ( AssemblerTemplate 
                 : OutputOperands 
                 [ : InputOperands
                 [ : Clobbers ] ])

asm asm-qualifiers ( AssemblerTemplate 
                      : OutputOperands
                      : InputOperands
                      : Clobbers
                      : GotoLabels)
```

In your case you have an empty `OutputOperands` parameter:

```c
asm(
    
    // Assembler Template
    "mov R0,%0\n"
    "mov R1,%1\n"
    "mov R3,%2\n"
    "mov R4,%3\n"
    "mov R5,%4\n"
    
    :
    
    // OutputOperands
    // (none)
    
    :
    
    // Input Operands
    "r"(<A_VALUE>),
    "r"(<A_VALUE>),
    "r"(<A_VALUE>),
    "r"(<A_VALUE>),
    "r"(<A_VALUE>),
    
    :
    
    // Clobbers
    "r0","r1","r2"
    
)
```

Comment: Also note that this snippet of inline asm has Undefined Behaviour - it writes registers R3, R4, and R5 without declaring them as clobbered.  (Assuming this is compiled for an ISA that uses destination-first syntax like ARM, for example).  Also, you basically never want to use `mov reg, %0` as the first instruction of an asm template: instead ask the compiler to have the operand in that register in the first place.  e.g. by using `register int foo asm("r0")` as an operand like `"r"(foo)`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info